# JWT token base authentication on each request for dashboard app

Tags: authentication, jwt, token, login-system

I want to create a login system using JWT and have these questions:

**1-** My client login and I generate a token for him/her and store the token in local storage. Now If somebody else copies this token from local storage of this person browser and paste in his/her (I mean hacker)  browser local storage, this hacker will able to log in? If yes, is that safe?

**2-** I put user Id in the token that I generated On login function. On each request that is sending to the backend, I decode token and find userId in it. Now should I compare this user id by anything? Example checking that is there any session by this user ID in backend or even checking the user Id by DB?

**3-** should I put an expiration time for JWT token on the local store?

Answer (score 0):

1 - It's safe to store these in localStorage. It is worth checking out how to protect against [Cross site scripting](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) attacks; this is particularly true for high security environments. Users copying and pasting is probably an unlikely attack, and, if the user has physical access to do the copy and paster, there are probably other 'vulnerabilities' like just using the browser's stored passwords.

2 - The JWT encrypts the user id included in the claim. A user can't change this claim and keep it valid (assuming a strong key), so no need to check this elsewhere.

3 - Yep! Since the JWT has a claim (like the user roles) in it, you don't want those to be valid for forever. Also, you want to have a way to ensure that users re-verify their identify (ie. log in again) just in case something goes wrong/a token is stolen. When you put an expiration on the token, you force this.